# Android: Google Maps myLocation button - perform zoom in

Tags: java, android, maps

I'm intercepting the click from the mylocation button like so:

```
map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

 map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {

                                bMyLocationClicked = true;
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
```

and then making it zoom in like so:

```
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) parentActivity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

LocationListener myLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (bMyLocationClicked) {
            bMyLocationClicked = false;

            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18f));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
};

// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, myLocationListener);
```

Everything works fine, except that there's an extremely long delay between pressing the mylocation button and the zoom in actually happening. The centering of the map finishes and about 2 seconds later the map actually zooms in. How can I speed this up?

I'm looking for an answer where I stay using the mylocation button rather than implementing my own.. although, if there's absolutely no alternative, I'll build a custom center/zoom button.

Comment: try returning `true` from your `onMyLocationButtonClick` method.

Comment: have you tried `animateCamera` option? move camera will show you end result without animating it.

Comment: @ImMathan won't returning true prevent the mylocation button from centering on my location?

Comment: If its taking time, return `true` and manually animate the camera.